# How to remove surveyJS io surveycreator properties like Quiz/timer options?

Tags: surveyjs

How to remove surveyJS io surveycreator properties like Quiz/timer options?

How to remove surveyJS io surveycreator properties like Quiz/timer options?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial to learn how to hide Survey Creator settings: [Hide Properties from the Property Grid](https://surveyjs.io/survey-creator/documentation/property-grid#hide-properties-from-the-property-grid).